# can MAMP run without internet?

Tags: localhost, mamp

When ever I lose my internet connection, localhost configured in MAMP is not accesible. no root, no sites, no sites with no internet based dependencies. I've user WAMP in the past and have not found this problem.
This has me thinking there's a background process requiring internet access.
Is there anyway to configure MAMP so I don't need an internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

I looked up for my IP address (System Preferences > Network ) and used it as
http:// MYIPADDRESS/

instead of using 'localhost'

Add port if need to.

Answer (score 0):

So far you have described above. There is nothing special while using internet because by using WAMP, MAMP or XAMP all works at your local host. so look at other setting, like if you found php.ini in wamp.

Comment: What exactly should I be looking for? MAMP settings and configurations are not extended and I wouldn't really know what to look for in console or something like that. PHP is settled to 5.4.10 , cache php extensions to none. Ports 80 Apache and 3306 Mysql

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when my wireless network kept losing internet connection. Switching off wifi completely - so disabling all network connections solved the problem for me.

Mac Pro OSX Mavericks MAMP